# Custom password policy setting on samba 4

Tags: linux, ubuntu, samba, password-management, password-protection

samba 4.3.4

smb.conf : https://paste.ubuntu.com/23809659/

passwd check file : https://paste.ubuntu.com/23809667/

I have set everything according to documentation still the custom password policy doesnt work.

It let me use simple passwords and doesn't check the password with the script.

Comment: How are you actually changing the passwords?

Comment: As it is zentyal server im using the web portal to change password as admin.And also i tried logging in as the user and tried to change the password still it allows me to use weak passwords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used

```
libpam-pwquality
```

and modified the /etc/pam.d/common-password file
Added the parameters i wanted and all set!!!